# How to manage elements that are the same across multiple pages

Tags: html

Brand new to html/css, is there a way to manage recurring elements on a site such as a toolbar? For example, if I have a website with 10 pages and want to change the HTML for the universal toolbar, do I have to change it on all 10 pages?

Comment: Start using a template.

Comment: which tool you use to write the html?

Comment: The keywords are `Ajax` (javascript approach) and `Frameset` (not supported in html5). Another approach is using a server-side template engine (raintpl,...)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be a **server-side include**.

Meaning, you have:

- index.php
- head.php
- footer.php
- nav.php

And in `index.php` you looks something like:

```
<?php include_once "head.php"; ?>
Actual content here
<?php include_once "footer.php"; ?>
```

`head.php` for example, would look like:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <?php include_once "nav.php"; ?>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: if you use `php` anyways you should use a template engine, i.e. [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [raintpl](http://www.raintpl.com/)

Comment: @ultima_rat0: Or you could use a full fledged framework. But let's not get ahead of ourselves here. You learn the language first, then the libraries. That's the normal workflow.

Comment: @ultima_rat0 , why would anyone want to use some outdated crap like smarty?

Comment: Just a hint for the future. @tereško: last release in June2013. It's just a bit slow, but the template syntax is quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If the HTML is written in 10 different places then Yes, you have to change it on all 10 pages.
If you're adding the HTML to all pages through a common usercontrol(if you are .net that is) or using a template, then you can do it in 1 place & be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean having recurring items check out Madara's answer. If you mean recurring styles, the following will give you an example:

If you want a certain text to show up as red every time, you can name it "Red":

In css:

```
.red{
color: red;
}
```

The "." indicates its a recurring element and you can name it whatever you want as long as its being used in the html.

In html:

```
<span class="red">Sample text</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have few options:

1. Use some server-side language (i.e. PHP) - recommended
2. Use [iframe tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe):

   <iframe src="toolbar.html"></iframe>

Comment: Funny, I took the first google result for the iframe tag. I'm new here, but if this anti-w3schools mood is the reason for the downvote, then that person should think about himself. It's like "don't ever talk about IE here, it's bad browser and someone might start using it"..

Comment: It's because beginners learn from w3schools.. and they're learning not from the best tutorials there - [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: w3schools promotes outdated, sometimes blatantly wrong information, without giving the option for community edit, or even proper feedback.  That's why giving a link to w3schools to a beginner will earn you a few downvotes on the site. Also, IE *is* a bad browser, but some of us must support it out of requirement. No one requires you to link to w3schools.